# сортировка по убыванию/возрастанию из xml

Tags: сортировка

Здравствуйте!
Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать сортировку товаров по убыванию/возрастанию. Все данные берутся из .xml (баз данных нету).
Должно выглядеть так:
Сортировать: <по умолчанию>     <дешевле сверху>        <дороже сверху>

Пример, как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[https://market.yandex.ru/search?text=стабилизатор%20напряжения%20220в%20для%20дачи&clid=545&local-offers-first=0&deliveryincluded=0&onstock=1](https://market.yandex.ru/search?text=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20220%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8&clid=545&local-offers-first=0&deliveryincluded=0&onstock=1)

Первый пункт "по-умолчанию" должен работать по следующему принципу:

1. если для данного урла не указано правило, то пусть список товаров формируется без изменений, как его раньше и формировал движок сайта;
2. если для данного урла прописано правило, какие товары и в какой последовательности должны быть, то выводить товары в соответствии с их нумерацией (выше товар со значением "1" ниже - со значением "12")
   данные нумерации товаров по каждому урлу брать из .xml файла.

При клике по "дешевле сверху" - первым и самым верхним будет товар с самой маленькой ценой, а самым последним и самым нижним будет товар с самой большой ценой.
при клике по "дороже вверху" - наоборот.

Изначально оба варианта сортировки должны быть ссылкой. если человек уже нажал на один из пунктов, то после выполнения сортировки, этот пункт должен перестать быть активным (ссылкой) и стать обычным текстом.
Адрес страницы при этом не должен меняться.

Comment: Приведите пример XML. Чем Вы его парсите?

Comment: вопрос с сортировкой по цене решился (хоть и немного другим способом, как хотелось).

Comment: актуальной осталась 1я задача: очередность товаров на страницах категорий.
чем парсится xml? это делает сам движок.
xml с данными по товарам:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<shop>
<products>
 <product code="tovar-1">
  <one>1</one>
  <two>17</two>
  ...
  ...
 </product>
 <product code="tovar-2">
  <one>2</one>
  ...
  ...
 </product>
 ...
</products>
</shop>
в xml указано, что в категории "one" первым будет tovar-1, за ним пойдет tovar-2 и т.д.
в категории "two" tovar-2 буден на 17м месте.